# NDSolve: Using time delays in a WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I was wondering whether there is a way to use `WhenEvent` in a system of delay differential equations, for example:

```
z[t_] = Piecewise[{{1, t <= 5}, {3/2, 5 < t <= 10}}, 2];
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1, y'[t] == x'[t] - x'[t - 1], 
 WhenEvent[x[t - 1] == z[t], x[t] -> 0], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0, y[t /; t <= 0] == 0 }, 
 {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 20}];
```

The issue seems to be that the `WhenEvent` doesn't recognize `x[t-1]` as a function and tries to evaluate the condition by throwing in the most recent `x` and `t` values. I'm not sure whether this is because `WhenEvent` can't access the value at `x[t - 1]` or because I need to input the condition in a way that explicitly tells it to go back and find this value.

---

A more complicated example to illustrate one of the systems I am working with:

```
n = 3; m = 2;
staff = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
P = {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {7/10, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 4/5}, {0, 0}}};
PT = {{75, 360, 720, 0.3}, {75, 420, 930, 0.4}};
PA = {{1, 7/10}, {0, 0}, {0, 3/10}};
v = {{7/2, 5}, {7/2, 9/2}, {15, 20}};

a[t_, i_, k_] := PT[[k, 1]]*PA[[i, k]]*PDF[
    TriangularDistribution[{PT[[k, 2]], PT[[k, 3]]}, ((1 - PT[[k, 4]])*PT[[k, 2]] + PT[[k, 4]]*PT[[k, 3]])]
  , t];

Ns[t_, i_] := Piecewise[Table[{staff[[i, k]], (k - 1)*30 <= t < k*30}, {k, 1, 48}]];

evts = Flatten[Table[With[{i = i}, {
   WhenEvent[Evaluate[Subscript[V, i][t] == 0] && Evaluate[Subscript[S, i][t] <= Ns[t, i]], Subscript[dv, i][t] -> 0]
   , WhenEvent[{Evaluate[Subscript[V, i][t] > 0], Evaluate[Subscript[S, i][t] > Ns[t, i]]}, Subscript[dv, i][t] -> 1]
   , Subscript[dv, i][t /; t <= 0] == 1
  }], {i, 1, n}]];

eqns = Flatten[Table[With[{i = i}, With[{p = p}, {Subscript[U, i, p]'[ t] == (Subscript[dv, i][t])*(Subscript[Q, i, p][t])*Ns[t, i]/(Subscript[V, i][t] + .001) + (1 - Subscript[dv, i][t])*Subscript[L, i, p]'[t - v[[i, p]]], Subscript[U, i, p][t /; t <= 0] == 0}]], {i, 1, n}, {p, 1, m}]];

rls = Flatten[Table[With[{i = i}
   , {Subscript[S, i][t_] -> Sum[With[{p = p}, Subscript[L, i, p]'[t - v[[i, p]]]*v[[i, p]]], {p, 1, m}]
    , Subscript[V, i][t_] -> Sum[With[{p = p}, Subscript[Q, i, p][t - v[[i, p]]]*v[[i, p]]], {p, 1, m}]
    , Table[With[{p = p}
       , {Subscript[Q, i, p][t_] -> Subscript[L, i, p][t] - Subscript[U, i, p][t]
        , Subscript[L, i, p][t_] -> Integrate[a[t, i, p], t] + Sum[With[{jj = jj}, P[[jj, i, p]]*Subscript[U, jj, p][t]], {jj, 1, n}], Subscript[L, i, p]'[t_] -> a[i, t, p] + Sum[With[{jj = jj}, P[[jj, i, p]]*Subscript[U, jj, p]'[t]], {jj, 1, n}]
      }]
      , {p, 1, m}]
     }]
   , {i, 1, n}]];

NDSolve[
  Flatten[{evts, eqns} //. rls]
  , Flatten[Table[ With[{i = i}, {Subscript[dv, i][t], Table[With[{p = p}, {Subscript[U, i, p][t]}], {p, 1, m}]}], {i, 1, n}]]
  , {t, 0, 1000}
  , DiscreteVariables -> Flatten[Table[With[{i = i}, Subscript[dv, i][t]], {i, 1, n}]]];
```

This example gives fairly decent results without the time delays, but bad things start happening when any element in `v` gets too large.

Comment: Is this too simple an example? It seems to me that since `x'[t] == 1`, `y'[t]` will always be zero, and so `y` is constant, unless it's supposed to know about the discontinuity in `x[t]` that arises as a consequence of the reset `x[t] -> 0`, but in that case, you actually have an impulse for `y` (because of the infinite derivative at those points), and I'm not sure that `NDSolve` can deal with that.

Comment: Sorry - I should have been clear that the example was just to illustrate what I'm trying to do with the `WhenEvent` and that the equations (especially `y[t]`) are not relevant. I am only interested in whether there is a way to get the `WhenEvent` to recognize `x[t-1]` as a function instead of directly substituting the most recent values.

Comment: My first thought was to define an auxiliary function `a[t]` and include `a[t] == x[t - 1]` and `a[t/;t<=0]==0` in the list of equations. I tried `NDSolve[{x'[t] == t, a[t] == x[t - 1], WhenEvent[a[t] == 1, x[t] -> 0], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0, a[t /; t < 0] == 0}, {x[t], a[t]}, {t, 0, 20}];` as a simple example, but `NDSolve` had problems once it was time for `a` to reset (one time unit after `x` resets). Perhaps we could make this work, but I'm not sure how to fix the resetting problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's something I came up with to get you started. Consider this an extended comment until we can figure out how to make this work..

The idea is to use an auxiliary variable `a[t]` that is a `DiscreteVariable`, and use it to find the times at which `x` crosses `z`. We set the value of `a[t]` to be that particular time and then use `WhenEvent` to reset `x` one time unit later.

I will use a simplified version of your code that doesn't actually involve the delay piece involving `y`.

```
timeLimit = 10;
z[t_] = Piecewise[{{1, t <= 2}, {3/2, 2 < t <= 5}}, 2];
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1/1.5 t
   , WhenEvent[x[t] == z[t], a[t] -> t]
   , WhenEvent[t == a[t] + 1, {x[t] -> 0, a[t] -> 0}]
   , a[t /; t <= 0] == timeLimit
   , x[t /; t <= 0] == 0}
  , {x[t], a[t]}
  , {t, 0, timeLimit}
  , DiscreteVariables -> {a}];
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], z[t], a[t]} /. %], {t, 0, timeLimit}]
 , Plot[{t, t - 1}, {t, 0, timeLimit}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Black, Dashed, Opacity[0.5]}}]
 ]
```

[image]

The blue curve is the solution for `x[t]`, the orange curve is `z[t]`, the green curve is `a[t]`, and the dashed lines are the functions `t` and `t - 1` that are acting as aids for the eye to show that `a[t]` gets set to the current value of `t` and is then reset to `0` after 1 time unit has elapsed.

There are some important observations.

- We can see that `a[t]` gets set to `t` when `x[t]` crosses `z[t]`: at these points, `x`, `z`, and `a` all cross.
- We can see that `x[t]` gets reset to `0` when one time unit has elapsed since `a[t]` gets set to `t`.
- Most importantly, we can see that the solution is not perfect: between the second and third resets, `x` crosses `z` twice, and `a` gets set only once. The first crossing is not detected for some reason.

This last point illustrates a second possible weakness of this method: if there is a second crossing of `x` with `z` within one unit time step (i.e. before `x` gets reset), then `a` might get over-written with the *new* time, and so `x` won't reset until one unit time step after the *new* time.

To illustrate this last problem, change the first two lines in the code above to

```
timeLimit = 4;
z[t_] = Piecewise[{{1, t <= 2}, {2, 2 < t <= 5}}, 2];
```

and run the rest of it. This results in:

[image]

It's worse than I feared! `a[t]` gets set by `WhenEvent` to the current time `t` when `x` crosses `z` at about `t == 1.8`. `a[t]` gets set again at `t == 2` when `z` jumps from having a value of `1` to having a value of `2`; in other words, this is interpreted as a crossing between `x` and `z` even though `z` exhibits a discontinuity here! Finally, `a[t]` gets reset one more time when `x` crosses the new value of `z`, which occurs *before* `t == 3`, and since `a[t]` was set to `2` at the second "crossing", `x` won't get reset before `t == 3`. Finally, `x` resets at about `t == 3.5`.

The upshot: this is a good idea, but I don't know exactly how to make it robust.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately, this doesn't extend easily to something like `WhenEvent[x1[t-1]+x2[t-3]==z[t],{...}]`. I will try to post a more complicated example to demonstrate why I'm so fixated on putting time delays in the `WhenEvent`.

Comment: @polkabug. Yeah, it seems like this method wouldn't generalize to that use case. Thus, the best bet is demonstrated by Michael E2, but as I noted, it seems to  break when the new variables try to reset. I don't yet know how to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

Almost a solution: I feel that one ought to be able to integrate the delayed values of the variables via equations such as

```
x1[t] == x[t - 1], y2[t] == y[t - 2]
```

and use the variables in `WhenEvent`.  It works in the following:

```
z[t_] = Piecewise[{{1/22, t <= 1}}, 2];
foo = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 2 t, y'[t] == x'[t] - x'[t - 1],
    x1[t] == x[t - 1], y2[t] == y[t - 2],
    WhenEvent[x1[t] + y2[t] > z[t], {x[t] -> 0, y[t] -> 0}], 
    x[t /; t <= 0] == 0, y[t /; t <= 0] == 1/2,
    x1[t /; t <= 0] == 0, y2[t /; t <= 0] == 1/2},
   {x, y, x1, y2}, {t, 0, 3}];

ListLinePlot[{x, y, x1, y2} /. First[foo]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But that seems to be an accident.  Extend the integration to `{t, 0, 4}`, and you'll get

> NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at t == 3.20710674525188`; unable to continue. >>

Integrate `x'[t] == 2 Sqrt[t]` instead of `x'[t] == 2 t` and I get a **kernel crash**!!  Maybe it's a bug??

Comment: I noticed this too, which is why I went the DiscreteVariable route. It crashes when the new variables are supposed to reset based on when x was reset.