# NDSolve with only discrete variables

Tags: differential-equations

Is is possible to use `NDSolve` with `DiscreteVariables` if there are no continuous-time variables?

This fails:

```
NDSolve[{x[0] == 1,
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, x[t] -> -x[t]]}, {x}, {t, 0, 7}, 
    DiscreteVariables -> {x}]
```

It works if I remove the `DiscreteVariables`, replacing it with $x'(t)=0$:

```
NDSolveValue[{x[0] == 1, x'[t] == 0,
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, x[t] -> -x[t]]}, {x}, {t, 0, 7}]
```

(This seems to defeat the purpose of `DiscreteVariables`.)

It works if I introduce a "dummy" continuous-time variable:

```
NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == 0, y[0] == 0, x[0] == 1, 
    WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1] == 0, x[t] -> -x[t]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 7}, 
    DiscreteVariables -> {x}]
```

(This seems like a hack.)

I ask because I have a system of equations

$$x_i(T_i^{k+1})=\sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} x_j(T_i^k), \quad i=1,\ldots,N$$

where each variable $x_i(t)$ changes only at the discrete times $\{T_i^k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Thoughts?

Comment: I often use the dummy-variable "hack" to drive DAEs.  -- Might be considered a design flaw, or one might think the D in NDSolve should mean something.  :)

Comment: I see what you mean, but if NDSolve isn't the right tool for this, is there a more appropriate function I'm overlooking?

Comment: I think it's the best available tool, even if it's not the best imaginable tool. `NDSolve` is the only built-in way to construct a discontinuous `InterpolatingFunction` (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98349/) for a manual method). If if one knows ahead of time the times that the variable changes, one could directly construct a `Piecewise` function (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34235/) or [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113064/))....

Comment: ...I view your problem as an "differential-order-0" form of "integration" (in the sense of putting together a function). `FunctionInterpolation` takes a global approach like `NIntegrate`. `NDSolve` takes a local approach, but primarily for order > 0; however, via DAEs, it can simultaneously do order-0 integrations. I don't think there's an analog of `FunctionInterpolation`.

Comment: I see. Thank you @MichaelE2 !

Comment: Update: I discovered that `WhenEvent` also doesn't support time delays as discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99576/ndsolve-using-time-delays-in-a-whenevent). This made `NDSolve` seem ill-suited for my problem. I filed a bug/feature report with Wolfram and solved the system of equations "by hand".

Comment: Update: The Wolfram folks suggest using `RecurrenceTable` like this: `RecurrenceTable[{x[t + 2] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, x[1] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 
  10}]`. This addresses the `NDSolve` example above but not for the weird hybrid system of equations I wrote out in math.