# Spurious Error Messages from NDSolve when Using WhenEvent with Time Delays

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs, event-detection, warning-messages

**Bug introduced between versions 10.1 and 10.4, and resolved in 11.3.**

Using either 11.2 or 10.4 on Windows 10 (64 bit), I am unable to reproduce the [answer by March](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99669/187) to question 99576.  Specifically,

```
timeLimit = 10; 
z[t_] = Piecewise[{{1, t <= 2}, {3/2, 2 < t <= 5}}, 2]; 
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1/1.5 t, WhenEvent[x[t] == z[t], a[t] -> t], 
    WhenEvent[t == a[t] + 1, {x[t] -> 0, a[t] -> 0}], 
    a[t /; t <= 0] == timeLimit, x[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, 
    {x[t], a[t]}, {t, 0, timeLimit}, DiscreteVariables -> {a}];
```

> NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {x[t],a[t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined. >>

Is this a bug?  Is there a work-around?

**Work-Around**

[Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) provides a work-around in a comment below, "change `a[t /; t <= 0]` to `a[0]` and the same for `x`".  It also works for the problem I originally set out to solve, a delay differential equation, but only because my initial conditions for `t <= 0` are constant.  Even then, Mathematica 11.2 returns the warning message

> NDSolve::ihist : Conditions given at t = 0 will be interpreted as initial history functions for t /; t <= 0.

before returning the correct answer.

**Addendum:** "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" gives the correct answer without error or warning messages.

Comment: I face the same issue on `V11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows 7 (32-bit)`.

Comment: @March, your answer to question 99576 seems to have stopped working.  What version of Mathematica were you using when you submitted that answer?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey In version 9 it works.

Comment: @bbgodfrey. I was and still am using V10.0.1 on a Mac. The code still works for me.

Comment: You can change `a[t /; t <= 0] ` to `a[0]` and the same for `x`.  The conditional notation does not seem to be necessary here.  That said, I would report it.

Comment: @Szabolcs  Your solution works, even though the real problem I am trying to solve, a delay differential equation, throws the warning message `NDSolveValue::ihist :  Conditions given at Notebook$$17$150701`t = 0 will be interpreted as initial history functions for Notebook$$17$150701`t/;Notebook$$17$150701`t<=0.` before giving the desired answer.  I shall report the problem.  Many thanks.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive post title, that makes it clear what the issue is related to.

Comment: @JasonB.  Is the new title along the lines of what you had in mind?

Comment: Perfect - that makes it much more likely a future user who has the same issue can find the question!